# DataServiceQuery for unknown entity in TableStorage Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I,

Here is my situation.

I have a worker role in my Azure who needs to constantly read rows from a Table in tablestorage and do some actions with it. But the problem is you don't know which entity he is pulling. It could me a Customer or an Order or a any other entity.

So how can you pull like the first 100 rows or all, no mather what entity it is?

The current solution I'm working with is giving each row a 'Type' Column which describes what type of entity he is. Then I just do a REST request to my tablestorage and get the raw xml back and parse it. I read in the type and that's how I know which entity the row is.

Is this the right way or is there any better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**

This did the thing for me:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/f57cb566-cc7a-4b31-b1ab-47b6d16604af/

He implemented the writing methode but with some tweaking I managed to implement reading unknowntypes and getting a dictionary with the properties.